# HTML Disabled Button getting :active CSS Pseudo Class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

CSS:

```
button:active {
/* active css */
}

button:disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button disabled="disabled">Ok</button>
```

When I click the button the browser adds the button:active state making it look like it was clicked (even though it is disabled). I swear I thought :active was only added if the button was enabled.  What have I missed?

Comment: in which browser have you tested it?

Comment: Here's a test page: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/LRvra/

Comment: Nope. It appears that `:active` **will** be applied to disabled buttons.

Comment: Actually the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#concept-fe-disabled) never states that a disabled control cannot be `active`. It only says `A form control that is disabled must prevent any click events that are queued on the user interaction task source from being dispatched on the element.`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

From what I can tell, `:active` doesn't exclude `:disabled` elements. You can read the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act) if you'd like.

To solve your problem, you could exclude `:disabled` elements by targeting only `:enabled` elements with your `:active` selector:

```
button:enabled:active {
/* active css */
}

button:disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/LRvra/1/**

Comment: Dang; you beat me by 5 seconds.

Comment: `:disabled` wasn't in the CSS2.1 spec.

Comment: @BoltClock: Thanks, I've included a link to the CSS3 spec.

Comment: This appears to work in Firefox/latest Chrome.  We don't support CSS2.1 anyway :P

Comment: @Justin Thomas: Ah, but you *are* supporting CSS2.1 when you support CSS3, since CSS3 is essentially CSS2.1 with bells and whistles.

Answer (score 4):

[According to the CSS3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-css3-selectors-20110929/#enableddisabled) (`:disabled` is not in CSS2.1) there is no mention that `:active` and `:disabled` are mutually exclusive. It's possible that this part of the specification needs clarification so UAs are free to apply the pseudo-classes in combination.

I suggest you modify your selectors to be more explicit:

```
button:enabled:active {
    /* active css */
}
button:disabled {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the :not()-descriptor of css:

```
button:active:not(:disabled) {
/* active css */
}

button:disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Wish y'all the best, Patric